# How to enable LSCV bandwidth on AniMove 1.4.2 (QGis 2.14.4)?

Tags: qgis, kernel-density

I'm trying to make some Kernel Analysis for animals home range and the option "LSCV" of bandwidth selection isn't appearing, the plugin give me only three options (rule of thumb (Scott), rule of thumb (Silverman) and custom). How could I enable LSCV option?

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in their [GitHub page](https://github.com/geomatico/sextante_animove) (albeit a few years old now):

> NOTE: some of the bandwidth methods are only available with scipy 0.11 (custom bandwidth value) and **statsmodels 0.5** (LSCV, maximum-likelihood cross-validation).

QGIS comes bundled with scipy so you may need to install **statsmodels 0.5** yourself to get the LSCV functionality.